# Elasticsearch re-ordering results that have been sorted

Tags: php, sorting, elasticsearch

I am using a single elasticsearch node as a cache for a basic php website that shares events. I am facing a problem with sorting the documents by date just after updating one. This is the first time I have used elasticsearch and it was most appealing for the geolocation searching.

So the scenario is:

I have two documents:

```
{
   "_index" : "giveback",
   "_type" : "event",
   "_id" : "1",
   "_score" : 1.0,
   "_source":{ 
      "id":"1",
      "title":"document1",
      "location":"",
      "start_time":"2016-01-26 08:30",
      "end_time":"2016-01-26 15:00"
   }
},{
   "_index" : "giveback",
   "_type" : "event",
   "_id" : "2",
   "_score" : 1.0,
   "_source":{ 
      "id":"2",
      "title":"document2",
      "location":"",
      "start_time":"2016-01-27 08:30",
      "end_time":"2016-01-27 15:00"
   }
},
```

Which I then query with:

```
{
    "size":100,
    "track_scores":false,
    "sort":{
        "0":{
            "start_time"{
                "order":"desc",
                "mode":"min"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which does give me document1 then document2 as expected. However if I then update document2's title or any other field that would not effect the sorting query. It will return document2 then document1 when I submit the GET query directly after.

Everything I have read so far suggests this should just work. Is there a problem with my sorting query?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Isn't doc1.start_time < doc2.start_time and you are ordering by asc

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out it must have got it mixed up while testing different things. I should be desc.